# Why is it possible to set a value in a slice using reflection?

Tags: reflection, go

According to [The Laws of Reflection](http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection) it is not possible to set the value of an element as follows, you need to use its address.

This will not work:

```
var x float64 = 3.4
v := reflect.ValueOf(x)
v.SetFloat(7.1) // Error: will panic.
```

This will work:

```
var x float64 = 3.4
p := reflect.ValueOf(&x) // Note: take the address of x.
p.Elem().SetFloat(7.1)
```

So why will the following work when using slices?

```
floats := []float64{3}

v := reflect.ValueOf(floats)
e := v.Index(0)
e.SetFloat(6)
fmt.Println(floats) // prints [6]
```

http://play.golang.org/p/BWLuq-3m85

Surely `v.Index(0)` is taking the *value* instead of address from slice `floats`, thus meaning it shouldn't be settable like the first example.

Comment: If you keep reading the 3rd law, it should explain it. It isn't as absolute as you've described it. "*Settability is determined by whether the reflection object holds the original item.*" In the 1st snippet, `v` doesn't hold `x` itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your first example, you pass the actual `x`. This will copy `x` and give it to `reflect.ValueOf`. When you try to do `v.SetFloat`, as it get only a copy, it has no way to change the original `x` variable.

In your second example, you pass the address of `x`, so you can access the original variable by dereferencing it.

In the third example, you pass `floats` to `reflect.ValueOf`, which is a slice. "Slice hold references to the underlying array" (http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#slices). Which mean that through the slice, you actually have a reference to the underlying object. You won't be able to change the slice itself (`append` & co) but you *can* change what the slice refers to.

Comment: `v.Index(0)` return a `reflect.Value`, not the *value* of the variable. In this case, `reflect.Value` hold the reference and not the value itself because it is a slice.